# Execute script when date matches mysql cell

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a debian machine with a mysql server.
On mysql I have a table that contains a number of rows with a datetime field.
How can I execute a php script when the date and time of the machine match with those specified in any mysql record? 
a) Mysql triggers ?
b) Deamon that runs in background and checks time every n seconds ?
c) Cron?

Let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution is to use , if possible , the [at](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) command.

Basically after inserting the data into mysql do the following:

1)Create (using PHP) a BASH script that runs the php file

**script_1.sh** should look like this:

```
!#/bin/bash

php /path/to/file.php
```

and make it executable with :

```
exec("chmod +x script_1.sh");
```

2)create a second BASH script that executes the first at the desired time:
**script_2.sh** should look like this:

```
!#/bin/bash

at H:M Y:M:D < script_1.sh
```

Make script_2 executable and run it with the exec command.

Answer (score 0):

Polling the MySQL will work but surely is not efficient, especially when there are a lot of "triggers".
So use a cronjob. Note: MySQL-Queries cannot schedule or cancel cronjobs. So the (i guess) PHP-Script updating that date field also has to schedule the cronjobs. Also, every time the column changes you will have to cancel the previously scheduled cronjob and schedule a new one.

Comment: So basically I would need to run a php script that : 1)Inserts data into mysql 2)Updates cron jobs accordingly..correct?

Comment: Thats how to do it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't run shell command from within Mysql database the MySql Triggers are no good.  The [MySQL Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) is therefore useless too. So you need an external script to help.

I'd suggest to create a (php) script and add it to the crontab to run every minute. Its task would be to check for matching dates in the database and run whatever command you need.